# whether it is possible find (in a runtime) all subclasses (which mixing some trait) using scala 2.10

Tags: scala, reflection, classpath, scala-2.10

i need find all subclasses which mixing some trait (i won't do this in a runtime). I know tool written in scala (ClassUtil) but this tool is slow. Also I know one tool written in java (fasters than ClassUtil), but if I have choice I wouldn't rather using external libraries - so my question is: scala 2.10 have support resolving my problem?

Comment: Subclasses of what? If you mean subclasses of a sealed trait, then yes, there's a straightforward way to do this in 2.10 with `knownDirectSubclasses`. If you want something more general it may be possible, but will be more challenging.

Comment: no, this isn't a sealed trait. Subclasses "have" own files and they extends directly trait which "have" another file

Comment: This is probably not helping you anymore, but this could be related to https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7046